# Tamil input support in Dialoglow with google assistant

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created a dialogflow ES with Webhook and integrated with Google Assistant. I want my Google assistant to accept inputs in Tamil language. But there is no Tamil listed in language section. Is there is any other way to accept my inputs in Tamil ? I enabled Hindi and said `Ek Baje`, it has accepted and I consoled with 1 a.m. I want to do the same with Tamil.

**Accepted language by Google assistant**

[image: Console]

**Webhook**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const df = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var voice =  "female";
var variant = "2"

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('We are live')
});


app.post('/', express.json(), (req, res) => {
    const agent = new df.WebhookClient({
        request: req,
        response: res
    });

    function getTime(agent) {
        let conv = agent.conv();
        var breakfastTime = agent.context.get('time');
            const ssml = '<speak> <voice language="ta-IN" gender="'+voice+'" variant="'+variant+'">' +
                'Thank you, Have a great day ' +
                ' </voice> </speak>';
            conv.ask(ssml);
            agent.add(conv);
        }

    var intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Time', getTime);

})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Sever is live"));
```

Comment: Actions on google does not support [Tamil language](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/languages-locales) but [Dialogflow does](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/language). Is it possible for you to forward the input text directly to the Dialgflow agent?

Comment: No, inputs are user given through voice..

Comment: Are any of those links useful? [Link 1](https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/362264/how-to-get-google-assistant-voice-in-tamil?hl=en), [Link 2](https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/964154/i-want-google-assistant-in-tamil-language-i-have-tried-but-there-is-no-tamil-option-pls-help-me?hl=en)